# Force compiler not to use .rodata section

Tags: pointers, gcc

Is there any way to force gcc to put

```
char* str = "Hello";
```

not in the .rodata without change this statement in

```
char str[] = "Hello!";
```

?

---

Ok, so better way to do this is modify the statement to `char str[]`. Thanks to all.

Comment: Build for a target that doesn't support .rodata?

Comment: Your first line should really read `const char* str = "Hello";`

Comment: But more importantly why would you want to rule out the one portable, standardised way of doing this?

Comment: Even with the second version, how could the literal possibly not be read-only, anyway? It's not like the literal is truly writeable in the second example, what's writeable is the _copy on the stack_.

Comment: I'm porting a program from local to a remote version using rpcgen. All the XDR function used to encapsulate data need pointers to editable areas.

Answer (score 4):

Why? Trying to change string literals leads to undefined behavior. It's evil. Consider this program:

```
"hello"[0] = 'y';   // Welcome to Undefined Behavior Land. Enjoy yor stay!
std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;   // Could very will print "yello" now!
```

Comment: I'm working on converting a long-lived code base with about 2.5 million lines of code to compile on a new platform and a more standards conformant compiler.

I finally got it to compile & link.  The first crash I encountered was because someone decided to take advantage of the fact that the previous compiler put everything in the .data segment.

This type of code needs to be removed from this codebase, but it is only one of over 40,000 problems discovered by clang's static analyzer and other wonderful tools.

Temporarily disabling this functionality would be helpful for a project like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
static char strbuf[] = "Hello";
char *str = strbuf;
```

Comment: This way I need to modify the original program, and that's just what I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strdup.html) if your platform has it, or implementing it yourself if it doesn't?

```
char *str = strdup("hello world");
```

This will allocate memory (at runtime) and copy the string literal into an appropriately sized chunk of memory which you can quite legitimately write to and modify later.

Don't forget to `free()` after use though.

You might be able to force GCC to put somethings in specific sections of your choosing using the `__attribute__ ((section ("my_section")))` [attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html), but you'll still have to modify the original source to do that so you'd be much better off doing it a "normal" way.